# Urls rewriting for a multilingual webpages

Tags: .htaccess

My actual page structure is like this:

```
https://example.com/try
```

What would be the best `.htaccess` rules to convert it to:

```
https://example.com/fr/essayer or https://example.com/en/try
```

What I have tested:

```
RewriteRule ^(fr|en)/(.*)\.php$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I can't change the page name to the french one.

Thanks.

Comment: what you need is to add fr or en ?

Comment: Cause my website has more than 1 language. Perhaps I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use URLs like `https://example.com/fr/pageA` or `https://example.com/en/pageA` while under the hood still serving up `https://example.com/fr/pageA or https://example.com/pageA` you could use a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|fr|de)/(.+) $2 [QSA,L]
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=c26eb9b8-7d31-51df-9072-0f218032dba3

Note that this does not pass the language code over, you could achieve that like so if needed:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|fr|de)/(.+) $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your help. I've changed a little bit the question to add the page name. Could you have a look again at the question please ? Sorry for this.